# GNU GRUB Minimal BASH-like line editing when boot after Ubuntu reinstall

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub2, boot-repair

I normally reinstall Ubuntu every couple months. I saved my important files in a hard drive and did a full reinstall, formatting my PC. After that whenever I boot my computer it opens Minimal BASH-like line editing screen comes up. My PC is a Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming with AMD Ryzen 7 and an NVIDIA GPU.

I tried using Boot-Repair and it didn't work. ([Here is the Pastebin generated](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/k5BzfctyR8/)). I also followed the instructions in this [itsfoss](https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/) tutorial to no avail.

```
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at sector 
    1 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,msdos5)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on nvme0n1p5

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Renoir from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, focal, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: FCCN16WW(1.16) from LENOVO
This live-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).


85fa9d77b929ec4231aba29476574eb6   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
fa1bf1a7f90a852abe0bdbd089b7f1b0   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
469e608783843a701d172242f016c79c   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 953.89 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x81bbc6c4
          Boot   Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
nvme0n1p1 *       2048    1050623    1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
nvme0n1p2      1052670 2000408575 1999355906 953.4G  5 Extended
nvme0n1p5      1052672 2000408575 1999355904 953.4G 83 Linux
Disk sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xb10b63e2
      Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
sda1        2048 976769023 976766976 465.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
Disk sdb: 14.42 GiB, 15472047104 bytes, 30218842 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x2cf4ba3a
      Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *          0  5999871  5999872  2.9G  0 Empty
sdb2       5271500  5279499     8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdb3       6000640 30218841 24218202 11.6G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:500GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA ST500LM030-2E717:;
1:1049kB:500GB:500GB:ntfs::;
sdb:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:unknown:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
nvme0n1:1024GB:nvme:512:512:msdos:KINGSTON OM8PCP31024F-AI1:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32::boot;
2:539MB:1024GB:1024GB:::;
5:539MB:1024GB:1024GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                     
└─sda1      ntfs     FC62D44B62D40BF0                     b10b63e2-01                          Nuevo vol                
sdb         iso9660  2021-08-19-11-03-38-00                                                    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS amd64 
├─sdb1      iso9660  2021-08-19-11-03-38-00               2cf4ba3a-01                          Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS amd64 
├─sdb2      vfat     54C5-9C6C                            2cf4ba3a-02                                                   
└─sdb3      ext4     6840b456-68b2-47ac-9b7f-0349bcc483f8 2cf4ba3a-03                          writable                 
nvme0n1                                                                                                                 
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     C043-DD8E                            81bbc6c4-01                                                   
├─nvme0n1p2                                               81bbc6c4-02                                                   
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4     e50beef4-968b-4400-9a8b-5dd49d88f880 81bbc6c4-05                                                   

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                                                Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-07-16.15/crash]  10.6G   1% /var/crash
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-07-16.15/log]    10.6G   1% /var/log
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                 505.8M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                 880.4G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/sda1                                                      465.7G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sdb1                                                           0 100% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-07-16.15/crash] ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2022-07-16.15/log]   ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/nvme0n1p1                                                 vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p5                                                 ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1                                                      fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1                                                      iso9660         ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 20d8a7d0-0bd5-49fc-8aaa-28566a18a87e root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   e50beef4-968b-4400-9a8b-5dd49d88f880
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-41-generic   e50beef4-968b-4400-9a8b-5dd49d88f880
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-27-generic   e50beef4-968b-4400-9a8b-5dd49d88f880
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=e50beef4-968b-4400-9a8b-5dd49d88f880 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=C043-DD8E  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p5: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 894.631454468 = 960.603209728  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             3
 890.641151428 = 956.318654464  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
   8.262195587 = 8.871464960    boot/vmlinuz                                   1
   5.775386810 = 6.201274368    boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-27-generic                 2
   8.262195587 = 8.871464960    boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-41-generic                 1
   5.775386810 = 6.201274368    boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
   9.139122009 = 9.813057536    boot/initrd.img                                1
   9.078685760 = 9.748164608    boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-27-generic              1
   9.139122009 = 9.813057536    boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-41-generic              1
   9.078685760 = 9.748164608    boot/initrd.img.old                            1

=================== nvme0n1p5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18224 Jan 11  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Aug 12  2021 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Aug 12  2021 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Aug 12  2021 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Aug 12  2021 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Aug 12  2021 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Aug 12  2021 41_custom



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would purge (in order to fix packages) and reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p5,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Blockers in case of suggested repair: __________________________________________

 The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode. This will enable this feature.

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
The boot of your PC is in BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to UEFI mode.
```

I have also tried doing what is said in other questions about this topic, but nothing worked.

Comment: You are mixing UEFI & BIOS and also mixing MBR(msdos) and gpt partitioning. With UEFI, you should normally use gpt. Windows requires gpt, UEFI recommends gpt, Ubuntu will let you use MBR with UEFI, but probably should not. You also can use gpt with old BIOS, if you really want to boot using boot mode from 1980's.  If willing to reinstall again, I would convert drive to gpt and reinstall in UEFI mode. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is how it installs. Converting to or from GPT - must have good backups.
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html If you use gparted, it will erase drive

Comment: I solved it by booting in legacy mode

Answer (score 0):

According to the Boot-Repair Boot Info Summary the boot of your PC is in BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode. Boot your PC in legacy mode.